# Python xml read if have tag value using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to read this file if  "TypeOfVessel" value is not null.  list will be read if have "TypeOfVessel" value. Please see my code below. any suggestion please. Thanks

```
<ArrayOfConsolidatedList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <ConsolidatedList>
        <RegimeName>Test1</RegimeName>
        <Subsidiaries i:nil="true" />
        <TonnageOfVessel i:nil="true" />
        <TownOfBirth i:nil="true" />
        <TypeOfVessel i:nil="true" />
    </ConsolidatedList>
    <ConsolidatedList>
        <RegimeName>Test2</RegimeName>
        <Subsidiaries i:nil="true"/>
        <TonnageOfVessel>841</TonnageOfVessel>
        <TownOfBirth i:nil="true"/>
        <TypeOfVessel>Bunkering Vessel</TypeOfVessel>
    </ConsolidatedList>
</ArrayOfConsolidatedList>
```

Python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import inspect

def ListParse():
    tree = ET.parse('ListRead.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    all_entity_entries = root.find("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}ArrayOfConsolidatedList")
    for entry in all_entity_entries:                                                
        RegimeName = entry.find('RegimeName').text
        TonnageOfVessel = entry.find('TonnageOfVessel')
        TypeOfVessel = entry.find('TypeOfVessel')
        print(TypeOfVessel)
            
ListParse()
```

Comment: What should be the output? What is your current problem?

Comment: I want all value in this list all_entity_entries if have "TypeOfVessel" value. I'm getting "all_entity_entries" variable is null . Thanks

Comment: `ListParse()` does not return any value. Change the code and make it return what you need.

Comment: I will some database work with this TypeOfVessel value and then return data from database. that portion I didn't include here. Thanks

Comment: Based on the XML you have attached, what is the expected output? Add it to the post.  Why do you have `matches` and `country_list` in the code? Clean the code, share the expected output and explain what is the problem

Comment: Better way to parse xml where "TypeOfVessel" value is not null and simple print value. That is the main point other  database thing I can do. I cleanup code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def ListParse():
    root = ET.parse('ListRead.xml')
    vessels_entries = root.findall("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}ConsolidatedList")
    for vessel_entry in vessels_entries:
        RegimeName = vessel_entry.find("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}RegimeName").text
        TypeOfVessel = vessel_entry.find("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}TypeOfVessel")
        TypeOfVessel_is_missing = TypeOfVessel.attrib.get("{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil", "false")
        print(RegimeName)
        print("missing" if TypeOfVessel_is_missing == "true" else "available")


ListParse()
```

outputs :

```
Test1
missing
Test2
available
```

EDIT: in comments you indicated that you don't want to have all the data in memory. Thus, you should use **event-based** parsing instead of **tree-parsing**, and use Python generators. Here is an example :

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_vessels_with_non_null_type():
    with open("ListRead.xml", "rb") as xml_file:
        parser = ET.XMLPullParser(["end"])  # we are only interested in the end of tags
        # now we read the file by chunk (deliberately low for example purposes)
        chunk_size = 10
        while True:
            chunk = xml_file.read(chunk_size)
            if chunk == b"":
                break  # end-of-file
            else:
                parser.feed(chunk)
            # the parser received a few more bytes, let's see if there is new vessels
            new_events = parser.read_events()
            for event_name, element in new_events:
                # we have to check the tag of the element that has just finished parsing for the one we are interested in
                if element.tag == "{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}ConsolidatedList":
                    # and we want to filter the ones which do not have a value for TypeOfVessel
                    TypeOfVessel = element.find("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}TypeOfVessel")
                    TypeOfVessel_is_missing = TypeOfVessel.attrib.get("{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil", "false")
                    if TypeOfVessel_is_missing == "false":
                        yield element


def do_something_with_a_vessel(vessel_entry):
    RegimeName = vessel_entry.find("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}RegimeName").text
    TypeOfVessel = vessel_entry.find("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}TypeOfVessel").text
    print(RegimeName, TypeOfVessel)


for vessel_entry in get_vessels_with_non_null_type():
    do_something_with_a_vessel(vessel_entry)
```

output : just `Test2 Bunkering Vessel`

This reduces the memory footprint to a near minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is it possible to have only available data in TypeOfVessel . I to want get data where TypeOfVessel  data is available. xml file is so large so want only  TypeOfVessel data list.  here findall only pull data if TypeOfVessel  data available.    vessels_entries = root.findall("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}ConsolidatedList")

Comment: @Letoncse simply `print(TypeOfVessel.text)`, you will have a `None` when it is missing, and `Bunkering Vessel` when it is available.

Comment: is it possible to get all vessels_entries only TypeOfVessel value is available ? I don't want to pull out all because it will be thousand of records. Thanks   vessels_entries = root.findall("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}ConsolidatedList")

Comment: @Letoncse I updated my answer to add a solution based on streaming : it will read the file a chunk at the time, produce events when an element is ready to be inspected, which is ignored if it does not match, so that only `ConsolidatedList` with non-null `TypeOfVessel` get `yield`ed, one by one, when requested.